# How to convert hexadecimal to decimal in Pig Latin?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

My sample file has a column which has a four digit hexadecimal (7AA0) which I need to convert into decimal (31392). Any idea how to do it?

I came across the following code over the internet which does the vice-versa using Java inbuilt class, but I cant make out how to do the other way round:

```
--invoker.pig
define hex InvokeForString('java.lang.Integer.toHexString', 'int');
divs  = load 'NYSE_daily' as (exchange, symbol, date, open, high, low,
        close, volume, adj_close);
nonnull = filter divs by volume is not null;
inhex = foreach nonnull generate symbol, hex((int)volume);
```

Comment: That code is calling [`String Integer.toHexString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-). For reverse logic, you need to call [`int Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-), with value `16` as the second argument. I have no clue as to how to do that in Pig, but you should be able to figure that out.

Comment: I tried with InvokeForInt('java.lang.parseInt','String'); . But this did not work for me.

Comment: My guess is that you'd need `define txttoint InvokeForInt('java.lang.Integer.parseInt', 'String', 'int')` and call as `txttoint((String)inhex, (int)16)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define hex InvokeForInt('java.lang.Integer.parseInt','String int','true');
a = LOAD 'hex.txt' using PigStorage() as (hex:chararray);
b = foreach a generate hex($0, 16);
dump b;
```

if hex.txt contains:

```
abc
10
1
1abc
```

the code above would print

```
(2748)
(16)
(1)
(6844)
```